# How to Delete older .sqlaudit file except top 2

Tags: sql-server

we are having SQL server audit enabled to a file based which has max rollover setting to 40 files,
We want to do following process

- read and get incremental records & insert into table - which is done.
- Once read from file is completed, we don't want to keep the file and delete Manually - since sometime auto delete of file does not work.

We tried to read file property such as create date time and file name using t-sql however this datetime format generates in different format (dd-mm-yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd or dd/mm/yyyy etc) due to regional or other setting difference on other machines. so we can't rely on datetime setting we received from file attribute as converting to datetime was generating error due to invalid datetime in other server.

What i tried is here : https://mikesdatawork.wordpress.com/2018/02/05/get-file-names-and-create-dates-with-tsql/

So we are stuck to find to delete this older unused file , please help how we can acheive.

Comment: It's a little unclear if your question is about sorting the dates of files to delete, or if you don't know how to delete files that you've found using the script at the link you posted. Deleting the files should be easy enough with [xp_cmdshell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Hello Erik , thanks for reply. yes deleting is easy. However i am attempting to delete .sqlaudit file except top 2 based on file create_date desc order. this datetime can be in different format like yyyy-mm-dd or dd-mm-yyyy depending on regional machine location. While i fetch file name based on date time on other machine , it says invalid datetime. and need to develop a code that can format that as date properly.

Comment: You should be able to set the [date format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) locally based on what's in the `language` and `date_format` columns in [dm_exec_requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).